# Generating function for the "two variable totient"?

Tags: number-theory, totient-function, arithmetic-functions, coprime

Recall that [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\varphi(n)$ is defined as the number of natural numbers $<n$ which are coprime to $n$.
The Dirichlet series generating function for $\varphi(n)$ is
$$
\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{\varphi(n)}{n^s}=\frac{\zeta(s-1)}{\zeta(s)}.
$$
The Lambert series is
$$
\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{\varphi(n)q^n}{1-q^n}=\frac q{(1-q)^2}.
$$
For the "ordinary" generating function the only identities I know involve the Möbius function,
$$
\sum_{n\geqslant1}\varphi(n)x^n=\sum_{n\geqslant1}\frac{\mu(n)x^n}{(1-x^n)^2}=x\frac d{dx}\left(x\frac d{dx}\log\prod_{n\geqslant1}(1-x^n)^{-\frac{\mu(n)}{n^2}}\right).
$$

Now what I need is a similar expression of any such kind for the generating function of
$$
\varphi_2(n):=\#\left\{(a,b)\mid0<a,b<n<a+b,\gcd(a,b)=1\right\}.
$$
The sequence of the $\varphi_2(n)$ for small $n$ goes like
$$
0,0,0,1,1,4,3,7,8,12,11,19,17,26,28,32,32,45,42,56,58,65,64,82,80,94,97,109,107,131, ...
$$
It is not on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a square $[n-1]^2$ cut by the diagonal $x+y=n$.
The number of points in the square is $2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\phi(k)$.
Remove the points on the diagonals $x+y=k$, which is $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\phi(k)$
Final sum is $$-\phi(n)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\phi(k)$$

Another way to look at it.  Compare $\phi(n+1)$ with $\phi(n)$.  Include points of the form $(a,n)$ and $(n,a)$, and remove points of the form $(a,(n+1)-a)$.  If $a$ and $(n+1)-a$ are coprime then so are $a$ and $(n+1)-a+a$.  So $$\phi_2(n+1)=\phi_2(n)+2\phi(n)-\phi(n+1)$$

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. I need the number of points above the line $x+y=n$, you claim it is the same as below that line? What is your final expression for $\varphi_2(n)$?

Comment: Now I see it, thanks for expanding!